# Java + Swing: Is there a way to make a "TitledBorder" invisible?

Tags: java, swing, border, titled-border

I've created a `JFrame` with a `JPanel` on it, that gets visible/invisible by clicking on an item in a list. I want to have a `TitledBorder` (that's also the class name) go around it.

I already tried a few methods (`setVisible`, `setBorderPainted`) but none of them apply for the class. Also I can't find a suitable method in the Java doc!

My goal is to have the border invisible when the panel is, and visible when the panel is. All kind of solutions would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a titleBorder in the jPanel is done as follows:

```
yourPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("your title"));
```

And to hide it would be:

```
yourPanel.setBorder(null);
```

I hope I've helped. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I want to answer my own question because i just found a solution that may help others:
Replace your titledBorder with an emptyBorder, when there shouldn't be any border visible:

```
Border emptyBorder = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder();
yourComponent.setBorder(emptyBorder);
```

This should overwrite the existing border and be completely invisible.

Comment: Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). One card would be a panel with the border (and component(s)), the other would be a blank panel. This will preserve the bounds as needed for the titled border, while swapping it for an `EmptyBorder` will require some guesswork (e.g. the font might be a different size on different PLAFs or platforms).